# onChange in dojo not working in ie8

Tags: dojo, onchange

My code is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore");
  dojo.connect(dijit.byId('_department_id'), 'onChange', function (val) {
    alert("Department" + val);
    $.getJSON('${desigForDept}', {
      paramID: val
    }, function (data) {
      alert("Department");
      poplulateDesigItems(data);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: same code working in ff and chrome

Comment: What sort of DOM element is `_department_id`, and what version of Dojo?

Comment: _department_id is a id of element @PaulGrime

Comment: I understand that, what is the DOM element's type.

Comment: To be a bit picky, I don't think combobox is a DOM element, so I've assumed it's a `<select>`.

Comment: dom element is input type not select @PaulGrime

Answer (score -1):

This works for me in IE8. This is the 'pure' DOM way (i.e. not necessarily the dijit way).

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.0/dojo/dojo.xd.js.uncompressed.js'></script>

<select id="_department_id">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>

<script>
dojo.ready(function () {
    console.log("ready");
    var id = "_department_id";
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    dojo.connect(el, 'change', function (val) {
        alert("Department" + val);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: No @paul as i am using spring roo it is working in FF and Chrome not in IE

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see how that's an issue. You might need to rework the question.

Comment: Maybe seeing the accompanying HTML would help me improve my answer?